# How to delete the same random items from multiple arrays of equal length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-2.7

I have several arrays of size (20000,1) with different contents. I'd like to randomly delete 25% of all rows per array in such a way that for each array the same row is deleted.
A rather tedious way I found is the following:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array(range(1000))
b=np.array(np.random.rand(1000))
seed=np.random.randint(0,100000000)     #picking a random seed
np.random.seed(seed)      #Setting the same seed for each deletion
a[np.random.rand(*a.shape) < .25] = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
b[np.random.rand(*b.shape) < .25] = 0
a=a[a !=0]
b=b[b !=0]
```

There are several problems with this approach, such as what if an array already contains zeros?
Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

based on and extended from Joel Cornett's solution:

```
import numpy as np

length = 20000
limit = int(0.75*length)
keep = np.random.permutation(length)[:limit]

newArray = oldArray[keep]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-numpy solution in very general terms:

```
import random
to_keep = set(random.sample(range(total_rows), keep_ratio * total_rows))

#do this for each array:
new_array = np.array(item for index, item in enumerate(old_array) if index in to_keep)
```

- `total_rows` is the number of rows in each array (I think you said this was 20,000)
- `keep_ratio` is the percentage of rows to keep, which according to you is `1 - 0.25 = 0.75`

**EDIT**

You can also use numpy's `compress()` method.

```
import random
to_keep = set(random.sample(range(total_rows), keep_ratio * total_rows))
kompressor = (1 if i in to_keep else 0 for i in xrange(total_rows))

new_array = numpy.compress(kompressor, old_array, axis=1)
kompressor
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Theodros's answer, but preserves the original ordering of elements:

```
import numpy as np

mask = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
mask[:len(a)/4] = 0
np.random.shuffle(mask)

a = a[mask]
b = b[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how well this works with `numpy`, but this is what I'd use in pure Python:

```
total = len(a)
toss = int(0.25 * total)
keeping = [False] * toss + [True] * (total - toss)
random.shuffle(keeping)
a = [value for value, flag in zip(a, keeping) if flag]
b = [value for value, flag in zip(b, keeping) if flag]
```